# How do I configure the SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder to build center-facing gnomonic projected polygons on a WGS84 map?

Tags: geotools, h3

I am trying to tile historical political territories with H3 grid-defined tiles using Geotools. My input shapefiles use the WGS84/EPSG:4326 CRS. H3 hex grids are center-facing gnomonic projections, but I'm assuming they still use the WGS84 CRS. (Only because that's what Kevin Sahr uses in the DGGS software that inspired the H3 project, as I understand it).

I'm getting some odd results and I suspect the problem is because I'm not handling the gnomonic projection in my method; neither in placing the hexagons nor in saving the resulting polygons in the shapefile output.

Here's my method:

1. ingest a shapefile of territories (polygons and multipolygons)
2. extract the boundary(ies) collect the hexagons that fit in that     boundary at resolution 3 (or 4, in some efforts) with the  `h3.polyfillAddress()` method
3. build and save a shapefile for that set of hexagons, using a Geotools `SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder`

[image: Unresolved Projection of H3 Tiles onto EPSG:4326 (WGS84) Map of Central Asian Khanates in 1815]

The geojson input for the input polygon is at: https://pastebin.com/wH1SgCY8

The geojson output for the H3 tiles is at: https://pastebin.com/0Zuc7awv

The shapefiles near the center of the map--Prime Meridian/Equator viewed with QGIS--seem correct, but the farther from the center I get strange results. The projection is clearly a problem, but I don't know if the strange polyfill results are caused by some limitation of H3's polyfill method or because the projection of the input boundaries should have been handled before attempting the polyfill operation.

My SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder the specifies output with WGS84 CRS. Should I be doing some transformation from a gnomonic projection (to ?) for each polygon before building it?

Here's the code:

```
   private static void saveShapefile(String name, String abb, Set<String> hexes) throws IOException {
    /*
    Takes a country name, it's abbreviation and a set of hexagons that will represent it and writes out a shapefile

     */
    String filename = "src/main/data/hexMaps/politicalBoundaryHexes_" + yearString + "_" + name + ".shp";
    File file = new File(filename);

    H3Core h3 = H3Core.newInstance();
    List<SimpleFeature> features = new ArrayList<>();
    GeometryFactory gf = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();

    DefaultFeatureCollection output = new DefaultFeatureCollection();

    final SimpleFeatureType HEX = createFeatureType();
    SimpleFeatureBuilder featureBuilder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(HEX);

    ShapefileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory = new ShapefileDataStoreFactory();
    Map<String, Serializable> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("url", file.toURI().toURL());
    params.put("create spatial index", Boolean.TRUE);

    ShapefileDataStore dataStore = (ShapefileDataStore) dataStoreFactory.createNewDataStore(params);
    dataStore.createSchema(HEX);

    int index = 0;
    for (String h:hexes) {
        List<GeoCoord> geocoords = h3.h3ToGeoBoundary(h);
        int numVerts = geocoords.size();
        Coordinate[] coordinates = new Coordinate[numVerts + 1];
        if(debugging){System.out.println("Processing hex " + index + ", @ " + h);}
        for (int i=0; i<geocoords.size(); i++){
            coordinates[i] = new Coordinate(geocoords.get(i).lat, geocoords.get(i).lng);
        }
        coordinates[numVerts] = new Coordinate(geocoords.get(0).lat, geocoords.get(0).lng);
        Polygon polygon = gf.createPolygon(coordinates);
        Object[] values = new Object[]{polygon, index, h};
        index++;
        featureBuilder.addAll(values);

        SimpleFeature polyFeature = featureBuilder.buildFeature(h);
        features.add(polyFeature);
    }

    org.geotools.data.Transaction transaction = new DefaultTransaction("create");
    String typeName = dataStore.getTypeNames()[0];
    SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = dataStore.getFeatureSource(typeName);

    if (featureSource instanceof SimpleFeatureStore) {
        SimpleFeatureStore featureStore = (SimpleFeatureStore) featureSource;
        SimpleFeatureCollection collection = new ListFeatureCollection(HEX, features);
        featureStore.setTransaction(transaction);
        try {
            featureStore.addFeatures(collection);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            transaction.rollback();
        } finally {
            transaction.close();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Writing the Shapefile failed.");
        System.exit(1); // Failure!
    }
}

private static SimpleFeatureType createFeatureType() {
    SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
    builder.setName("polygon");
    builder.setCRS(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);
    builder.add("the_geom", Polygon.class);
    builder.add("id", Long.class);
    builder.add("address", String.class);
    final SimpleFeatureType TYPE = builder.buildFeatureType();
    return TYPE;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what's going on here, but I don't think it's due to H3. There's no need to deal with H3's internal gnomic projection; the output is simply unprojected lat/long points. To be clear, is the issue that you are getting the wrong hexagons out of `polyfill`, or that when you view the hexagons they appear to be in the wrong projection?

Comment: can you add a link to an example input file?

Comment: I've added a link to a geojson version of this territory and the hexes H3 generates. 

@nrabinowitz, I don't know for certain that I'm getting the wrong hexes from polyfill, but the projection is definitely wrong and the issue of polyfill seems like another issue. I can say that the hexagon at the far right is '8300eefffffffff', which has vertices at { 85.261243651 49.035859351, 85.489858680 56.333677994, 86.126882084 58.281167906, 86.558387097 50.654975319, 86.261554247 41.755501348, 85.612846324 42.206975309 } but the rightmost point in the territory is at ~94.3 51.6.

Comment: Following up in this, I am more convinced that I should be handling projections differently AND there seems to be a limitation with the `polyfill` method. I have an idea to work around itand will share it back tomorrow.
The projection seems a bigger problem, so I made several test shapes and placed them at intervals on the globe. Tall  (big North/South span) and compact (squares) shape come out OK (but somethimes in the wrong place) but wide (big East/West span) almost always breaks the polyfill and the resulting set of hexes seems to depict a 3-d globe/icoshedron, not a map projection at all.

Comment: I’ve confirmed that the geojson you pasted gets expected results from polyfill, so I don’t think there’s an H3 bug here (unless something’s wrong in Java - I tested in JS, but the underlying implementation is the same).

Comment: @nrabinowitz, would you mind posting the list of hex addresses returned by the polyfill method in JS?  I'm getting the same results even if I avoid GeoTools, altogether.

Comment: I get [282 hexes at res 3](https://gist.github.com/nrabinowitz/0cc51e3336e71906c58fd4c5bea87a27) - as you can see from the screenshot, they appear to be correct.

Comment: @nrabinowitz OK, something else is going on here. I get 349 hexes, none of which are the 282 you get. I get the same 349 hexes from h3-java, h3-js, and h3-py. https://pastebin.com/EEvAhqUa  

Probably, this is not really a question any more and I should report it as an issue on the main H3 GitHub page.

Comment: Just to be thorough, the issue here was that H3 expects coordinate data as (lng, lat) but my GeoJSON was presenting it as (lat, lng). This has to be dealt with both on the input and in the output.